# How to get more than one results with preg_match_all and file_get_contents

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents, preg-match-all

i'd like to get more than one result using the fuction mentioned in the title, so far i'm just able to get just an only value using preg_match. I'd like to get an array of all the results and then record them in my db.

That's my current code:

```
$casturl = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/353491-the-dark-tower/cast";
$cast = file_get_contents($casturl);
preg_match_all('|<img class="profile lazyload fade" data-sizes="auto" data-src="(.*?)" data-srcset="|' , $cast , $castimg );    
print_r($castimg);
```

When i print the results i'm just giving: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>

I made sure cast contains what i want. I've tried already a lot of possibilities and i got nothing :(

Comment: You *are* getting your results, but it's printing HTML so it gets messed up. Try using `var_dump($castimg);` and you'll see.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. I hope you grabbing all image URL's

```
$casturl = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/353491-the-dark-tower/cast";
$cast = file_get_contents($casturl);
preg_match_all('#<img class="profile lazyload fade" data-sizes="auto" data-src="(.*?)" data-srcset="#' , $cast , $castimg );    
print_r($castimg[1]);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w66_and_h66_bestv2/d9NkfCwczP0TjgrjpF94jF67SK8.jpg [1] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w66_and_h66_bestv2/jdRmHrG0TWXGhs4tO6TJNSoL25T.jpg [2] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w66_and_h66_bestv2/gzjmHOSM1vnwnXpU737tdu9YjOu.jpg [3] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w66_and_h66_bestv2/zYiS1KJKEoLstzFA3DV5gwszzSC.jpg [4] => https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w66_and_h66_bestv2/vDuvdRoliXbjQrptk7GVs4Qj07S.jpg ......)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use

```
var_dump($castimg);
```

instead

```
print_r($castimg);
```

you will see much more clear.